# Как склеить 3 картинки в 1 на php

Tags: php

Задача есть 3 изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить вот такой результат?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php) думаю тебе поможет

Comment: посмотрите вот на эти [вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D++%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8). в деталях наложения одного изображения на другое они все одинаковы